# Destination…not written because src files were empty?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using Grunt and receiving this particular error. Destination build/vendor/vendor.min.js,
build/js/allModules.min.js,
build/js/restFiles.min.js,
not written because src files were empty.

Is there some kind of other log file somewhere?

And This is my grunt file code

```
 var vendor = [
    "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
    "bower_components/jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js" ];
  uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false,
    compress: {
      drop_console: true
    }
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
        'build/vendor/vendor.min.js': vendor,
        'build/js/allModules.min.js': modFiles,
        'build/js/restFiles.min.js': userFiles
    }
  }
}});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post your entire Gruntfile.js

Comment: The paths to your source files are not resolving. Check your `cwd` and the paths.

Comment: This is not a valid Gruntfile. Post the whole thing.